# Validate delegated method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following three models:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Model
  has_many :teams_players
  has_many :players, :through => :teams_players
end

class TeamsPlayer < ActiveRecord::Model
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :player

  delegate :position, :to => :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Model
  has_many :teams_players
  has_many :teams, :through => :teams_players

  # the database attribute 'position' exists on Player
end
```

A team can have multiple players, and a player can belong to multiple teams. However, a team can only have one player with position 'kicker'.

How can I create this unique validation?

I tried adding a validation on `TeamsPlayer` like this:

```
validates :position, :uniqueness => { :scope => {:team_id} }
```

But during the validation, rails runs a query checking the `type` column on the `TeamsPlayer` database table. Instead, I want it to recognize that it's a delegated method and check for it on the `Player` database table instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a validation on `Player`, it is a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods) on `Team`

Comment: Why would it be on `Team` and not `TeamsPlayer`? If I put it on `Team`, wouldn't I be able to add as many players with the same position as I want? I just expose a form for creating `TeamsPlayer` objects

Comment: When validating a constraint like X can only have one Y, I put the validation on X, so I would put the validation on `Team` to check that it only `has` zero or one kickers.  I suppose you could put a validation on `TeamsPlayer`, I've never tried it.

Comment: I'm creating/editing/destroying the join model using it's own controller, so I don't think I CAN put the validation on X. I think they would only run if I tried to modify X, which I'm not.